# Gson - is it possible int fields in quote (") when create json from object?

Tags: android, serialization, gson, deserialization

I am using gson lib to create json from objects. Backend developers are asking to create all values should be in "" quotes event int/long/boolean fields. For example my json looks like that:

```
{
  "age": 26,
  "email": "norman@futurestud.io",
  "isDeveloper": true,
  "name": "Norman"
}
```

-> i need the following format:

```
{
  "age": "26",
  "email": "norman@futurestud.io",
  "isDeveloper": "true",
  "name": "Norman"
}
```

Should i change all my fields from int to String or is there any way to do that? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just convert integer or Boolean to String

Answer (score 0):

To achieve this only way is to store Int as String and then converting the Data class to json String.As Gson use auto typecasting, you can't tell Gson to convert int to String and give you json.

Create the **POJO** according to your output json that is the only go.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is JavaScript object literal, not a JSON.
Well try this out!

---

> var obj = {"age": 26,"email": "norman@futurestud.io", "isDeveloper":
>   true, "name": 
>                "Norman"};
>
> for (var k in obj)   {
>
> ```
> if (obj.hasOwnProperty(k))
> {
>     obj[k] = String(obj[k]);
> }
> ```
>
> }